# Intellij IDEA isn't loading 'session' variable on debug mode in Grails Project

Tags: java, session, grails, intellij-idea

The `session` variable isn't loading in Intellij IDEA. In controllers, the variable seems null value.

If I create a watch in Debug Mode, Intellij returns `session = Cannot find local variable 'session'`

I'm using Intellij IDEA 11.1.5 but it seems this problem was solved in IDEA 10. I found an issue

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63227

In comments, a person advise to create a watch with this workaround:

```
getProperty("session")
```

But the error persists. My Grails version is 2.1.1 and JSDK version is 1.7u40

What I do?

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot that. Grails version is 2.1.1. Question edited! Thanks